# run background task using Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We are presently using the org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean and org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean to achieve the job scheduling for a specific cronExpressions and we have a requirement now to trigger a background process on some action i.e. similar to JMS.

I am looking for options using the quartz scheduler and can i add the task as a job in SchedulerFactoryBean (without specifying the cronexpression)and call it from a Java class ? 
Help required to explore this option. Thanks in advance

thanks for the reply. I did try this option
this is the spring xml config

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"> 
<property name="triggers"> 
<list> 
    <ref bean="TEST_SCHEDULER" /> 
</list>
</property>
<property name="autoStartup"><value>true</value></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="TEST_SCHEDULER" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="IN_TEST_SCHEDULER" />
    <property name="cronExpression"><value>"00 00 00 ? * MON-FRI"</value></property>
</bean>
<bean name="IN_TEST_SCHEDULER" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.TestScheduler" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="timeout" value="20" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

calling these statements from a java class

```
SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler(); //scheduler is null here .. 
scheduler.triggerJob(jobName, jobGroup);
```

The scheduler is null hence not able to trigger job ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution after exploring few sites and posting it just in case someone like me looks for it in future :)

```
WebApplicationContext springCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        scheduler = (Scheduler) springCtx.getBean("scheduler");
scheduler.triggerJob("IN_TEST_SCHEDULER", "DEFAULT");
```

this triggers the required job

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` bean to your class.
Call `getScheduler()` method on this bean in order to retrieve the scheduler instance. Use the scheduler to add additional triggers (simple, cron, etc.) for your desired job.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try this option but it did not work and edited my question as well. Thanks for the help